# javascript page title edit

Tags: javascript

I'm rubbish in javascript, but I need to do a little dynamic editing of my page title in the tab bar on my php site.

When the user on my site gets a mail, I want to change the title from "My site - Page" to "My Site (1) - Page"

I know how to change the page title with

```
<script>
   window.parent.document.title = "My Site (x)";
</script>
```

But what I need to do is grab the current title, eg "My Site - Page", and change it to "My Site (x) - Page". So I would need some twiddling with the string.

Don't worry about what the x is, I just need a hand with the javascript not the PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (change X as needed):

```
window.parent.document.title = window.parent.document.title.replace('-', '(' + X + ') -');
```

Or you can simply do:

```
window.parent.document.title = 'My Site (' + X + ') - Page';
```

**EDIT: Dynamic 'page' part:**

```
function trimString(s) {
  var l = 0, r = s.length - 1;
  while(l < s.length && s[l] == ' ') l++;
  while(r > l && s[r] == ' ') r -= 1;
  return s.substring(l, r + 1);
}
var t = window.parent.document.title;
var page = trimString(t.split('-')[1]);
window.parent.document.title = 'My Site (' + X + ') - '+page;
```

Comment: This is good, but say I dont know what "page" is, and wanted to grab that from the current title.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work just fine:

```
var x = 5;
title = title.replace("My Site", "My Site (" + x + ")");
```

Comment: Not good. You will get "My Site (3) (2) (1)" after several mails.

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can get and then set the title using javascript:

```
function showTitle(){
  alert( document.title );
}

function changeTitle(txt){
  document.title = txt;
  alert( 'Title changed to ' + document.title );
}
```

In order to inject your php you would just pass it in as a parameter aka: the `txt` parameter already in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var title = {
   theme: "My Site (<@>)",
   replace: function( txt ){
       document.title = this.theme.replace('<@>', txt)
   }
};

title.replace("something"); // title is My Site (something)


title.replace("something else"); // title is My Site (something else)
```

etc